# Собрать статистику по кол-ву подключений и запросов в разрезе часов

Tags: sql-server

Можно ли без профайлера собрать статистику какой IP выполнял какое кол-во запросов в разрезе часов или MS SQL никуда это не пишет?

Comment: Не пишет, но может - _event session_ нужно настроить. Насчёт IP, правда, не уверен.

Answer (score 1):

Для этих целей существуют [расширенные события](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/extended-events/extended-events) (*extended event sessions* или просто *event sessions*).

Для того, чтобы отследить

> какой IP выполнял какое кол-во запросов в разрезе часов

можно, например, создать сессию, которая будет отслеживать события

- `sqlserver.rpc_starting`
- `sqlserver.sql_batch_starting`

вместо этих двух событий, или в дополнение к ним, можно отслеживать событие

- `sqlserver.login`

смотря что требуется. Вместо IP будем собирать `client_hostname`:

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [ClientStats] ON SERVER 
ADD
    EVENT sqlserver.rpc_starting(
        SET collect_statement=(0)
        ACTION(sqlserver.client_hostname)
    ),
ADD
    EVENT sqlserver.sql_batch_starting(
        SET collect_batch_text=(0)
        ACTION(sqlserver.client_hostname)
    )
ADD
    TARGET package0.ring_buffer(
        SET max_memory=(2048)
    )
WITH (STARTUP_STATE=OFF);
GO
```

В этом примере данные собираются в *ring_buffer*, но вам, скорее всего, нужно будет их собирать в файл.

Когда требуется стартуем сессию

```
ALTER EVENT SESSION [ClientStats] ON SERVER
    STATE = START;
GO
```

Если нужно отслеживать события постоянно, то можно при создании сессии указать `WITH (STARTUP_STATE=ON)`.

Вычитываем данные из *ring_buffer* в рабочую таблицу:

```
DECLARE @ringBuff xml;
SELECT
    @ringBuff = cast(t.target_data as xml)
FROM
    sys.dm_xe_sessions xes
    JOIN sys.dm_xe_session_targets t ON t.event_session_address = xes.address
WHERE
    xes.name = 'ClientStats' and t.target_name = 'ring_buffer';

SELECT
    [host_name] = x.c.value('(action[@name="client_hostname"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(128)'),
    time_stamp = x.c.value('(@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime')
INTO #data
FROM
    @ringBuff.nodes('/RingBufferTarget[1]/event') x(c);
```

Анализируем

```
SELECT
    [host_name],
    [date] = cast(time_stamp AS date),
    [hour] = datepart(hour, time_stamp),
    [req_count] = count(1)
FROM
    #data
GROUP BY
    [host_name], cast(time_stamp AS date), datepart(hour, time_stamp)
ORDER BY
    [host_name], cast(time_stamp AS date) DESC, datepart(hour, time_stamp) DESC;
```

Если сессия не нужна больше, то её останавливаем:

```
ALTER EVENT SESSION [ClientStats] ON SERVER 
    STATE = STOP;
GO
```

(дабы не создавать дополнительную нагрузку на сервер).

Чтобы собирать данные в файл нужно при создании сессии задать `TARGET` типа *event_file*

```
ADD
    TARGET package0.event_file(
        SET
            filename=N'D:\XELogs\ClientStats.xel',
            max_file_size=(250), -- limit to 250Mb
            max_rollover_files=(0)
    )
```

(либо через `ALTER SESSION`, но тогда `TARGET` добавится как дополнительный). При этом у аккаунта инстанса SqlServer должны быть права на соответствующую директорию (`D:\XELogs` в примере).

Вытащить данные из XE-лога в рабочую таблицу можно запросом

```
SELECT
    [host_name] = x.c.value('(event/action[@name="client_hostname"]/value/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(128)'),
    time_stamp = x.c.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime')
INTO #data
FROM
    sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('D:\XELogs\ClientStats*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL) F
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML)) x(c);
```

и дальше можно анализировать данные так же как и в предыдущем случае.